# Move port-channel pair to new switch

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, netapp, cisco-nexus

So I have an old Nexus 3524 that is set up with a bunch of port-channel pairs connecting to three different ESXi hosts and four different NetApp nodes.  I am replacing that with a pair of Nexus 9000's in a vPC configuration.

I've created a new port-channel to flow traffic between the old Nexus and the new stack and it's working fine for management traffic.  I've also created new vPC port-channels on the new pair of switches to host each of the existing pairs connected to the old switch.

Is there a good non-disruptive way to move the pairs of ports from the old Nexus port-channels to the new vPC Nexus 9000 port channels?  For the NetApp, I can just migrate the lif off of a port group that I want to move, move them, and then migrate it back home.  That'll work for NFS and CiFS traffic, but iSCSI traffic and intercluster traffic might not like it.

I guess I'm most curious what will happen if I move one of the ESXi connections at a time to the new Port-Channels.  Anyone tried it?

I'm going to do it in a maintenance window, but I'm just looking to hear what folks have experienced and learn what to expect.